# Split an array or list when founds a "#"

Tags: python, arrays, string, numbers, data-science

I want to split an array when that for loops founds a "#", i'm trying to make a simulation in console and this is how the user will see.

But I can't found in no where a way to make this work.

```
 def grid(self):
        while True:
            size = input("Size of Map (N x N): ")
            if size.isnumeric() and int(size) >= 2:
                intSize = int(size) * int(size)
                mapH = list()
                map = list()
                for elementos in range(1, intSize + 1):
                    if elementos%10 == 5 or elementos%10 == 0:
                        mapH.append(elementos)
                        mapH.append("#")
                    else:
                        mapH.append(elementos)
                for el in mapH:
                   # I don't know what to make here
                return map
            else:
              continue
```

Comment: Are you trying to build rows and columns here?  And by the way, saying `if elementos%10 == 5 or elementos%10 == 0:` is exactly the same as `if elementos%5 == 0:`.

Comment: Yep, i want to build columns, but i failed lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why on earth do you ask the user for a size, if you hardcode the rows to 5?

```
def grid(self):
    while True:
        size = input("Size of Map: ")
        if size.isnumeric() and int(size) >= 2:
            size = int(size)
            intSize = size * size
            mapH = list()
            map = list()
            for elementos in range(1, intSize + 1):
                if len(mapH) == size:
                    map.append(mapH)
                    mapH = []
                else:
                    mapH.append(elementos)
            return map
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is one `#` in the array.

```py
i = 0
splitArray = []
for element in inputArray:
    if element == "#":
        splitArray = inputArray[:i]
    i += 1
```

Comment: I agree with this, but it would be much smarter just to create it as rows and columns in the first place.  It's silly to build a 1D list and then change it to 2D afterward.

Comment: @TimRoberts definitely agree with you, their implementation in general is a bit of a nightmare.